# Change Content-Type of JSON response while using 'as JSON' to render response

Tags: json, grails, content-type

It seems as if in Grails, the default contentType used to render a JSON response when using something like what follows:

```
render Book.list(params) as JSON
```

is application/json

There is of course a more longhanded way to define the content type:

```
render(contentType:"text/json") {
    book(title:b.title,author:b.author)
}
```

Is there a way to use the shorthand way, and still get a response content-type of "text/json"?

Note:  examples taken from [here](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your grails `config.groovy` you can set the following mime type properties.

```
grails.mime.types = [ html: ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
                xml: ['text/xml', 'application/xml'],
                text: 'text/plain',
                js: 'text/javascript',
                rss: 'application/rss+xml',
                atom: 'application/atom+xml',
                css: 'text/css',
                csv: 'text/csv',
                all: '*/*',
                json: ['application/json','text/json'],
                form: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data'
]
```

Try changing the order of the list of values for the json property to `['text/json','application/json']`

Comment: It doesn`t wokr as we have:
/**
     * Directs the JSON Writer to the Outputstream of the HttpServletResponse and sets the Content-Type to application/json
     *
     * @param response a HttpServletResponse
     * @throws ConverterException
     */
    public void render(HttpServletResponse response) throws ConverterException {
        response.setContentType(GrailsWebUtil.getContentType("application/json", encoding));
        try {
            render(response.getWriter());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(e);
        }
    }

in JSON.java