# Reading Response Content in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy

How could I read the response content in Grails (It is binary data)? Any sample code is 
appreciated.

Comment: Think this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150882/change-content-type-of-json-response-while-using-as-json-to-render-response

Comment: It's string type. response.contentAsString could be used for string type but it is not working for binary data.

Answer (score 0):

DataController:

```
class DataController {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

    def doSomeThing() {
        def myData = dataService.dataMethod(params)
        render(view: "show", model:[myData:myData])
    }
............
}
```

show.gsp:

```
...........
<!-- show response data -->
${myData}
<!-- thats it -->
```

Comment: data is binary (multipart).